# Using variables in html in a dynamically created component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I try to use a variable from an object that is sent to a dynamically created component. Everything works fine except displaying variables from the object in HTML. Styles on a dynamic component work.T he variable from method getData is not showing in HTML but showin in dev console.

Dynamic create :

TS FROM COMPONENT WHERE I CREATE OTHER WHEN CLICK

```
onMarkerClick(marker: Marker,data: Data, e) {

    if(this.compRef) {
      this.compRef.destroy();
    }
    const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(InformationPopupDataComponent);
    this.compRef = compFactory.create(this.injector);
    this.compRef.instance.getData(dataforPopupData);
    let div = document.createElement('div');

    div.appendChild(this.compRef.location.nativeElement);

    marker.setPopupContent(div);
    this.map.openPopup(div,marker.getLatLng());

  }
```

HTML (InformationPopupDataComponent) (the variable is not showing)

```
<div class="popup-container">
  <h3>Data {{data.d}} </h3>
<hr>

</div>
```

TS(InformationPopupDataComponent) (the variable from method getData is not showing in HTML but showin in dev console.)

```
export class InformationPopupDataComponent implements OnInit {

   private data: Data;
   public id;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  getData(data: Data) {
    if(data) {
      this.data= data;
      console.log("DATA", this.data.d);  <= showing
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: The property is private and therefore not shared with its template. When you compile for production (AOT), this will generate an error. Try removing the `private` accessibility keyword.

Comment: still not working

Comment: You could try changing the property to a getter/setter and see if that helps.

Comment: this not working too

Comment: Can you build a stackblitz demonstrating your issue?

Comment: do not show only those variables that are thrown in the method in which the component is created. The local variables of the component show up as it should be

Comment: How is `onMarkerClick` called? I'm wondering if this code is running outside of the Angular zone.

Comment: onMarkerClick is called when i create markers for map. Im looking  how iput data in dynamically created component,